# rotating and justifying tics in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to rotate the xtics by 45 degree. In another word the direction is `/`. Problem is the tics will appear inside the chart area, I want to put them outside of chart. See the figure:

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You must adjust both the alignment (can be `right`, `center` or `left`) and the `offset` (`x,y` coordinates with respect to the default tics position) of the `xtics`.

Here is an example, which demonstrates the three different possiblities. The `offset` must be adjusted manually, in order to get it right:

```
set xrange [0.5:3.5]
set bmargin 5
set multiplot layout 1,3

set xtics ('first' 1, 'second' 2, 'third' 3) rotate by 45 right
set title 'right aligned'
plot x

set xtics center offset 0,-1
set title 'centered'
replot

set xtics left offset 0,-2
set title 'left aligned'
replot
unset multiplot
```

This gives (with 4.6.4):

[image]

Comment: @mahmood Because for right alignment the default position is correct. In all cases you have the same default position, where the tic labels are placed. But if e.g. the label is left aligned, the label will reach into the plotting area (just try the script without any `offset`)