# Column and row name formatting in gnuplot

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I prepared a code to graph my script's csv output. They are column separated values.

I used code below to do that:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persist
set datafile separator ":"
set terminal png nocrop font small size 640,480
set output 'mychart.png'
set style data histograms
set title "some graph title"
set xlabel "some x asis name"
set ylabel "some ya axis name"
plot "/home/username/Desktop/test.csv" using 2:xticlabels(1) notitle
```

This will draw the graph successfully. However I have two problems here. One in x axis, there are big numerical values such as 50000000, 6000000 so graph shows them in exponential format such as 5E+9 6E+8. But I would like to see full number. Second, in y axis, there are almost 20 alphanumeric values (some network parameter names) and each of them with at least 25-30 character. So they won't show up properly. Is there a way to write them with a smaller font and an angle?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose you exchanged x and y axis, the y-axis shows the numbers.

Comment: I understood that, see my answer. But in your question you write that the big numbers are on the x-axis, but you mean y-axis :)

Comment: The places are correct. I mean x axis should show names, y axis should show numbers. That's fine. But output it's not good. As much as I understand, it writes x axis name horizontally, not vertically. Look at my graph: http://i1148.photobucket.com/albums/o569/Glockie74/mychart_zps4f75b80c.png

Comment: oh yea you're right :) My mistake sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the format of the numbers shown on the y-axis, use e.g.

```
set format y '%.0f'
```

The labels of the xtics can be rotated (`rotate by 45`), aligned differently (`right`) and they can use a different font size (`font`), e.g.

```
set xtics right rotate by 45 font ',8'
```

See also [rotating and justifying tics in gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19425683/2604213).

You may need to adjust the bottom border to have enough space for the labels, e.g. with

```
set bmargin 6
```

BTW: You should use the `pngcairo` terminal (available since version 4.4), which produced much nicer graphs than the `png` terminal.

Comment: Perfect. It just created the output I wanted. There are some minor issue with font sizing but easy to fix. Accepted and thanks.