# How to gnuplot a csv file containing temperature and humidity, label only every nth entry

Tags: csv, gnuplot

I have a `.csv` file, containing the log of a temperature / humidity sensor (*ELV TFD 128*). The data is logged every minute, like this (translation: "Number;Date;Temperature in degree Celsius, Humidity in %"):

```
Nummer;Datum;Temperatur in °C;Luftfeuchtigkeit in %
0;17-Nov-2013 9:54:14;25,90;52
1;17-Nov-2013 9:55:13;25,80;53
2;17-Nov-2013 9:56:12;25,50;53
3;17-Nov-2013 9:57:11;25,20;53
4;17-Nov-2013 9:58:10;25,00;53
5;17-Nov-2013 9:59:10;24,90;54
6;17-Nov-2013 10:00:09;24,80;54
7;17-Nov-2013 10:01:08;24,70;54
8;17-Nov-2013 10:02:07;24,70;54
9;17-Nov-2013 10:03:06;24,50;54
10;17-Nov-2013 10:04:05;24,50;54
(...)
```

I'd like to `gnuplot` the data, but only label every *n* th element (lets say, every 60th)  on the x axis with the second `csv` element - the date and time. As the label is quite long (`17-Nov-2013 10:04:05`), I'd like to angle the label away from the x axis by roughly 45 degrees so that the second "touches" (or points to) the x axis at the correct position.

As always, I'd appreciate any help or pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

In order to set the `xrange` and `tics` in `gnuplot` for a time axis, you can use something like the following

```
set xrange ["17-Nov-2013 12:00:02":"30-Nov-2013 12:00:00"]
set xtics border in scale 1,0.5 nomirror rotate by -45  offset character 0, 0, 0
```

Important is to set the time format correctly, i.e.

```
set timefmt "%d-%b-%Y %H:$M:%s"
```

See, i.e. `help set timefmt`, `help set xtics` for more detailed explanations. I didn't try, but with `set xtics` you should be able to suit it exactly to your needs, by specifying a spacing.

Comment: There is no need to have such a verbose command, `set xtics nomirror rotate by -45` is enough. The spacing of `set xtics` and time data is in seconds, so you can use e.g. `set xtics 5*60*60` for one tic every five hours.

Comment: @Christoph I copied from one of my scripts, so I agree some parts might be obsolete for this specific case.

Comment: Thats fine, just didn't want to confuse Christian :) And, to have the xtic labels 'touch' the axis, one needs to align the right, `set xtics right` like in [rotating and justifying tics in gnuplot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19425938/2604213).

Comment: Now, before I say "thank you" to everyone - how would I load the csv file into `gnuplot`? After issuing `plot "Desktop/test.csv"` (which I assume to be incorrect now ;) it complains `all points y value undefined!`...

Comment: I actually issued `plot "Desktop/test.csv" using 1:2:3` so as not to plot the sequence number. That gives the above error. Issuing `plot "Desktop\test.csv" using 2:3` plots an empty graph, saying `arning: empty y range [25:25], adjusting to [24.75:25.25]`.

Comment: This means that your third column contains `25` for each row.